# Trabajando con matrices "invalid value encountered in double_scalars"

Tags: python, matrices

estoy trabajando con matrices y para resolver sistemas de ecuaciones, en una parte del codigo tengo

```
    factor = (matriz_v[f,k]/matriz_v[k,k])
```

donde me sale el error "invalid value encountered in double_scalars"

creo que se debe a que esta trabajando con valores muy pequeños y python los esta igualando a cero y como no existe la division para cero me sale el error

quiero saber como hago para que trabaje con todos los decimales

encontre que usando

from mpmath import mp

pero no se como ponerlo en la operación de arriba

espero me logren ayudar, gracias

Comment: Te dejo la documentación del módulo [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/basics.html). Tiene algunos ejemplos __que tal vez deberías probar__.

Comment: Probablemente una división por 0. Saludos.